# Can engineered hardwood floors be refinished?

Tags: hardwood-floor, hardwood-refinishing, engineered-flooring

I want to replace the floors in the lower floor of my home.  I'm estimating about $8000 worth of work, installed.  My wife has been looking into engineered floors.  I have never been a huge fan of engineered, because I am under the impression that long term durability is not there. We have big pets and children. The chances of needing the floor stripped and refinished in under a decade is extremely high.  Can you even refinish an engineered floor?

Comment: Good write up on the differences: https://www.thespruce.com/engineered-hardwood-vs-solid-flooring-1821677

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the pros and cons of engineered hardwood?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4940/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-engineered-hardwood), among others.

Comment: The answer is yes, unless the initial quality is poor.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is maybe. Some engineered flooring the hardwood top layer is so thin refinishing would cut through to the plywood. If you chose a brand with a thicker hardwood surface then sure it could be refinished but use caution and don't use a heavy sandpaper or you will have the problem a friend of mine did. He was thinking his oak flooring was solid and wanted to change the color. He started sanding and peeled the top layer off, he called me to get the bad news he ended up replacing the entire room and hallway. So if you may want to refinish get at least 1/8" the 1/16 inch stuff really is so thin it can be done but you risk breaking through.